# How Do I Use querySelectorAll to Locate An Input ID and Update the Value of the Field?

Tags: javascript, e-commerce

I want to preface this by saying that I do not want to use jQuery for this particular task, so I'm trying like crazy to find a work around. I am trying to write something that deletes all the contents out of a shopping cart, but can't use any additional plugins or libraries, so I decided to take a straight JS approach.

My initial thought is to set the quantity values all to 0, and then resubmit the form to do this I found the input value for the field that sets the quantity, but it includes the product ID. Which ends up being something like quantity_item1
quantity_item2

So I can't simply use an getElementById, because the ID is changing, and that doesn't accept a wildcard value at the end. So I'm trying to use querySelectorAll, and then updating the value. However, it does not seem to be finding the quantity_ value when I test the function it returns a value of 0.

It is called onclick from the shopping cart, and here is the very basic function I've written. Any help would be appreciated.

```
function emptyCart(){
     var input =document.querySelectorAll(".quantity_");
     input.setAttribute('0', input.value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the class name, which was also in the tag. So my code ended up similar to this.

```
var input = document.querySelectorAll(".foo-bar");

for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    input[i].value = 0;
}
```